# Why does fsockopen have performance problems and not fopen when sending a POST request in PHP?

Tags: php, performance, post, fopen, fsockopen

I have tried two different implementations for simulating POSTing a form.  One uses `fsockopen` (example here: http://www.faqts.com/knowledge_base/view.phtml/aid/7962) and the other uses `fopen` (example here: http://netevil.org/blog/2006/nov/http-post-from-php-without-curl).

I ran into some serious performance problems with `fsockopen` - when I step through it with a debugger, everything seems to work just fine, but when I do not attach the debugger the page takes a looong time to load (probably more than 10 seconds).  `fopen` works perfectly (plus I don't have to parse out the response headers).  Does anyone know why `fsockopen` would have these performance problems?  Does it have to do with the timeout setting?

I've included my code below.

```
//fsockopen implementation
/**
 * The class that posts form data to a specified URL.
 * @package Core
 * @subpackage Classes
 */
class SU_form_poster_class
{
    /**
     * The file handle which is created when a form is posted.
     * @var resource
     */
    protected $file_handle;

    protected $port;

    protected $timeout;


    /**
     * Creates a new instance of this class.
     * @param int $timeout the timeout (in seconds) to wait for the request
     * @param int $port the port to make the request on
     */
    public function __construct($timeout = 30, $port = 80)
    {
        $this->timeout = $timeout;
        $this->port = $port;
    }

    /**
     * Sends a POST request to a specified page on a specified host with the
     * specified data.
     * @param string $path the part of the URL that specifies the page (including
     * the query string)
     * @param string $host the host part of the URL to post to
     * @param string $request_data the data to be posted in "query string" format,
     * e.g. name1=value1&name2=value2&name3=value3
     */
    public function do_post($path, $host, $request_data)
    {
        $err_num = 0;
        $err_str = '';
        $this->file_handle = fsockopen($host, $this->port, $err_num, $err_str, $this->timeout);
        if (!$this->file_handle)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException($err_str, $err_num);
        }
        else
        {
            $request = 'POST '.$path." HTTP/1.1\r\n".
                'Host: '.$host."\r\n".
                "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n".
                'Content-length: '.strlen($request_data)."\r\n\r\n".
                $request_data;

            fputs($this->file_handle, $request);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves data from the most recent request.
     * @return string the response
     */
    public function get_last_response()
    {
        if (!$this->file_handle)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException('A valid request must be made first.');
        }
        else
        {
            $response = '';
            $linenum = 0;
            while (!feof($this->file_handle))
            {
                $line = fgets($this->file_handle, 1024);
                if ($linenum > 6)
                {
                    $response .= $line;
                }
                ++$linenum;
            }
            fclose($this->file_handle);
            return $response;
        }
    }
}
```

```
/**
 * The class that posts form data to a specified URL.
 * @package Core
 * @subpackage Classes
 */
class SU_form_poster_class
{
    /**
     * The file handle which is created when a form is posted.
     * @var resource
     */
    protected $stream;

    /**
     * Sends a POST request to a specified page on a specified host with the
     * specified data.
     * @param string $url
     * @param string $request_data the data to be posted in "query string" format,
     * e.g. name1=value1&name2=value2&name3=value3
     */
    public function do_post($url, $request_data)
    {
        $params = array(
            'http' => array(
                'method' => 'POST', 'content' => $request_data
            )
        );

        $context = stream_context_create($params);
        $this->stream = fopen($url, 'rb', false, $context);
        if (!$this->stream)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException('Stream was not created correctly');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves data from the most recent request.
     * @return string the response
     */
    public function get_last_response()
    {
        if (!$this->stream)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException('A valid request must be made first.');
        }
        else
        {
            return stream_get_contents($this->stream);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTTP 1.1 connections default to persistent. This means the connection does not get automatically closed and `feof()` doesn't return true until the request times out. To get around this send the `Connection: close` header or use HTTP 1.0 which doesn't support persistent connections.

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know why fsockopen would
>   have these performance problems? Does
>   it have to do with the timeout
>   setting?

I've had problems in the past with fsockopen over ssl - but that isn't what your asking.

Have you tried using the curl_* family of functions instead, that might help?

Comment: I did try that, but I don't think that the servers that I would be deploying to would have PHP compiled with curl support (it's not the default).  I don't have a real problem here since `fopen` is working for me, but I am definitely curious why this is happening.